# Pandas split and select the second element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
item_id
26--_-23
24--_-65
12
24--_-54
24
66
23
```

When I say

```
df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].map(lambda x: x.split('--_-')[0])
```

I get:

```
item_id
26
24
12
24
24
66
23
```

Which is alright.
But when I say:

```
df['par_id'] = df['item_id'].map(lambda x: x.split('--_-')[1])
```

I get the following error:

```
df2['item_id'] = df2['item_id'].map(lambda x: x.split('--_-')[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then I decided to try:

```
def split(x):
    try: z = x.split('--_-')[1]
    except:  z = None
df2['par_id'] = df2['item_id'].apply(split)
```

But in this case, I get an empty par_id column
I know, it is probably a very trivial question, but what is the problem here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use pandas function [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select lists by positions by `str` - if values not exist get `NaN`s:

```
df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].str.split('--_-').str[1]
print (df)
  item_id
0      23
1      65
2     NaN
3      54
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
```

Detail:

```
print (df['item_id'].str.split('--_-'))
0    [26, 23]
1    [24, 65]
2        [12]
3    [24, 54]
4        [24]
5        [66]
6        [23]
Name: item_id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

split on space, slice off first item, join using commas:

```
df['Key'].str.split(' ').str[1:].str.join(',')
```